# The operation has timed out for email feature in powershell for windows 10

Tags: powershell

I am getting "Send-MailMessage : The operation has timed out" operation while running my powershell script. Below is the exception while i am getting

```
Send-MailMessage : The operation has timed out.
At C:\Users\f1ym41a\Documents\email.ps1:8 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -Smtp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

The code which i am using or my powershell sscript

```
$From = "user@domain.com"
$To = "user@domain.com"
$Cc = "user@domain.com"
$Subject = "Here's the Email Subject"
$Body = "This is what I want to say"
$SMTPServer = "someserver"
$SMTPPort = "25"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

Can anyone help me out why i am getting timedout exception?

Comment: Sometimes you get more info when you read the full error message `$error[0] | fl -Force` . What does it say?

Comment: writeErrorStream      : True
Exception             : System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
                           at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage.EndProcessing()

Comment: TargetObject          : System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo

Comment: ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Users\f1ym41a\email.ps1: line 8
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
PSMessageDetails      :

Comment: getting the above errors

Comment: It might be prompting for -Credential . It might be failing to resolve the DNS. The port might not be open. -verbose might provide more details. Does the .net equivalent run fine?

Comment: Smtp mail is deprecated due to it's reliability issues https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: i did telnet the smtp server with the port name and it is working fine

Comment: can anyone help me out with this?